# How can I render Cryptomatte pass for Nuke

Tags: rendering

I Rendered a test scene multilayer exr. It is include cryptomatte passes. Those passes work very well in after effects. But in Nuke, it is not.

[image]

Comment: When rendering out from Blender 2.8 straight as multi layer exr, everything works fine and you don't need to rename your view layers. But there still is a problem with multiple layers, because when outputing multi exr through Blenders compositor, something doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I found it!!! you need to rename your view layer to "scene" it's really akward but it works. wasted too much time on this... (using 2.8 thou), also no need to use the compositor to output the passes, it'll work just fine...

Comment: Please report this as a bug. Go to help menu. You´ll see a link to report.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the solution.
https://github.com/Psyop/Cryptomatte/issues/19

Screenshots with the main info:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just download the latest Cryptomatte plugin for nuke from pysop github, at least for me it work's
https://github.com/Psyop/Cryptomatte