# Cryptomatte issue

Tags: compositing-nodes, cryptomatte

I'm trying to add cryptomattes into my workflow and it is working just fine in blender compositor but I can't make them to work in any other software (Nuke, Davinci, After Effects). [image: Nuke]
[image: Blender Compositor]

What am I missing ?

Comment: Worked for me in [Fusion](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/163004/2214) ... for Nuke, does [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/129538/2214) solves your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems like it's an matte ID issue. I'm fairly new to the 3d world and actually don't really understand what they are talking about.

Comment: Tried again in Fusion, can't make it to work. Used OpenEXR this time, tried using MediaIn instead of Loader, same.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! It seams to work on Eevee but not on Cycles, so I re-rendered in Eevee with only the cryptopass.